# Merge Sort's running time in recursive version

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, mergesort

I learned that time function of merge sort is right below.

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(n) if n>1
```

I understand why `T(n) = 2T(n/2)+ A`

But why does `A = Θ(n)`?

I think `A` is maybe dividing time, but i don't understand why it is expressed as `Θ(n)`

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, **A** is not the dividing step. **A** is the merging step which is linear.

```
void merge(int a[], int b[], int p, int q, int c[])
/* Function to merge the 2 arrays a[0..p} and b[0..q} into array c{0..p + q} */
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < p && j < q) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            c[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < p) {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < q) {
        c[k] = b[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

This merging step takes `O(p + q)` time when `p` and `q` are the subarray lengths and here `p + q = n`.

Comment: I understand it, Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Accept answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I absolutely want it, but I don't know where the accept button is. T_T . How could I do it?

Comment: @오충현 Here you will find how to accept answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/200142

@pjs Good point. I didn't notice the `n` fact. I will use different notation

Comment: @pjs No problem, I appreciate your correction. Actually I am not very organized about the asymptotic jargons though I have working concept on it. You can edit my answer if you want :)